# Finding the analytic form of a power series

Tags: taylor-expansion

I have some power series that I'm pretty certain can be summed to an analytic function. Unfortunately, I don't seem to be able to figure it out by hand. The power series is:

$f(r_0,r_1)=\sum_{l=1} \frac{l}{r_0 a}\left(\frac{r_0 (2a-r_1)}{a^2}\right)^l$

Here, $r_0 < r_1$ and $a$ is a constant.

Based on physical intuition, the functional form should be some sort of inverse square law of the form

$f(r_0,r_1)\sim \frac{1}{|r_0-(2a-r_1)|^2}$.

Any ideas for how to tackle this particular problem?

Comment: Can you find $\sum_{l = 1}^{\infty} l\cdot x^l$ (for $\lvert x\rvert < 1$)? Then just substitute $x = \frac{r_0(2a-r_1)}{a^2}$ and multiply with $\frac{1}{r_0a}$.

Comment: Well that was easy. Thanks for the help! :)